# Target _blank added to anchors in Enhanced rich text column

Tags: 2013, splistitem

I have a SP List with an Enhanced rich text column whose purpose is to store HTML content which is then used to create the global navigation.

The problem is that target="_blank" is added to every anchor in my HTML code. Regardless of what changes are made to the column in the SP list item, this attribute is added to every anchor forcing the user to edit the markup code and remove it.

Is there any reason for this to be added? If so, how can it be disabled?

**UPDATE**

As requested, this here's a sample html which shows what I mean.

I create a new item and add this to the enhanced rich test column.

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-3">
      <h3> 
         <a class="gaTracking" id="Menu - Resources - Support" href="/Products/Support.aspx">Support</a>
      </h3>
   </div>
</div>
```

The item is saved correctly.

Afterwards, I go and edit the item, and when I look at the html source, this is what SharePoint displays:

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-3">
      <h3> 
         <a class="gaTracking" id="Menu - Resources - Support" href="/Products/Support.aspx" target="_blank">Support</a>
      </h3>
   </div>
</div>
```

The target="_blank" is new. We have hundreds of links, so removing every attribute every time we need to edit one of the list items is time-consuming. Not to mention that is very error-prone.

Comment: Are you adding the html from SharePoint form? Can you give us a sample html you are trying to add?

Comment: @ShashankReddyKaram Yes, I am. I have just included sample html as requested.